# module always returns null no matter what

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am new to node.js and was wondering why my code always return null.

I have db.js

```
exports.getItems = function(){
  var conn = mysql.createConnection();
  conn.connect();

  conn.query("Select * From Items", function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      conn.end();
      return rows;
  });
};
```

and the module is called like this:

```
var db = require('../db.js');
exports.items = function(req, res){
    var data = db.getItems();
    console.log('second', data);
    res.end(data);
};
```

and route:

```
app.get('/api/items', api.items);
```

The console.log('second') is always "second undefined". I have verified that the query is return items in the rows.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Classic async problem.

`getItems` is going to return before the database query is done.  The data from the database is returned in the callback, not in the function itself.

When you write:

```
var data = db.getItems();
console.log('second', data);
res.end(data);
```

the value for `data` is `undefined` because you don't have a `return` statement inside `getItems`!  So `getItems` returns undefined, as per the rules of JavaScript.

What you need is something like (and please understand I have not tested this) is:

```
exports.items = function(req, res){
  var conn = mysql.createConnection();
  conn.connect();
  conn.query("Select * From Items", function(err, rows, fields) {
    conn.end();
    if (err) throw err;
    res.end(rows);
  });
}
```

See various sites online for managing connections cleanly.  But this should be enough to get you to understand that the response should be sent from the callback of `query` which is where the data is actually available.

Comment: I changed the code to the following, but i keep on getting res is undefined!

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot call method 'json' of undefined" to be exact

Comment: Try printing the value of `rows` as the first line in the query callback.